# Read Cookie creation date (not "expiry date") || Java

Tags: java, cookies

I have a use case wherein I want to use **cookie creation date-time as condition** to do some operation.

Now the condition that I want to apply is that if cookies are more than 5 days old than do some operation else use existing cookies.

Please help.

Comment: Your profile says "Take chance and do experiments" - so what have you tried so far?

Comment: I was expecting this comment. I have found no ways as of now in java that can do so. 

Trying my luck now. 

Although there is one solution that I have found wherein I can create another cookie that can contain creation time of other cookies. Now this approach have one fallback that I'm introducing one extra cookie into application that is not very usable (only once to check 5 days validity condition) and my app already have number of cookies so I don’t want to introduce any extra cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know what system stores about a cookie is not the creation date but the expiring date. So It will not be possible to read it unless you try to read the last modified dates or something else (this will not work in many cases). But if the cookies are set by you you can set another cookie which holds creation time or even you can combine your cookie data to include the creation time

Comment: Dinesh, what you are saying make sense but there are two problems with this approach, one of which I have already mentioned in my comment earlier (I don’t want to introduce any new cookie in current application)

Secondly modifying existing cookie to add creation date time will impact whole application and that is not feasible now. So going with creating new cookie seems meaningful to me, unless there is another way. 

And one more thing when I say **“there in no way I can get cookie creation date in java from cookie is `true` in java isn’t it?”**